# ¿Cómo validar campos vacíos en angular material y obtener el id del campo a modificar?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular-material

Tengo el formulario con Angular Material,  donde se puede cambiar el campo **ESTADO** de la lista despegable y editar el campo **COMENTARIO** , lo que quiero hacer es que con el boton de **GUARDAR**  si le das click por primera vez y aun NO se ha modificado alguno de esos campos, mande una alerta de que no hay cambios, y si se llega a modificar alguno de esos, al hacer click obtener esos valores

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
<button mat-button (click)="guardar()">Guardar</button>
  <table mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource" class="mat-elevation-z8">

    <ng-container matColumnDef="idControl">
      <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> ID. </th>
      <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.idControl}} </td>
    </ng-container>

    <ng-container matColumnDef="cveEstado">
      <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> ESTADO </th>
      <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">
        <mat-form-field appearance="outline">
          <mat-select [(value)]="element.cveEstado" (selectionChange)="cambiarEstado($event.value, element)">
            <mat-option *ngFor="let estatus of estadoModel" [value]="estatus.cveEstado" [ngClass]="{'text-red':estatus.cveEstado=='ERR', 'text-blue':estatus.cveEstado=='INP'}">
              {{estatus.descripcion}}
            </mat-option>
          </mat-select>
        </mat-form-field>
      </td>
    </ng-container>

 
    <ng-container matColumnDef="comentario">
      <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> COMENTARIO </th>
      <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">
        <mat-form-field>
          <input matInput [value]="element.comentario" (keyup)="changeValue($event.target)">
        </mat-form-field>
      </td>
    </ng-container>

    <ng-container matColumnDef="horaInicio">
      <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> HORA </th>
      <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.horaInicio}} </td>
    </ng-container>

    <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></tr>
    <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;"></tr>
  </table>
```

Tengo lo siguiente en mi component

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { Control } from './Control';
import { ControlService } from './control.service';
import { MatTableDataSource } from '@angular/material/table';
import { Estado } from './Estado.ts';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'prueba-angular-material';
  displayedColumns: string[] = ['idControl', 'cveEstado', 'comentario', 'horaInicio'];
  estadoModel: Estado[]= [];
  control: Control[] = [];
  estadoSeleccionado: any;
  idSeleccionado: string = '';
  comentIngresado: string ='';


  constructor(private controlService: ControlService) {

  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.obtenerLista();
    this.obtenerListaEstados();
  }

  dataSource: any;
  private obtenerLista() {
    this.controlService.obtenerLista().subscribe(response => {
      this.control = response.data;
      this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource(this.control);

    })
  }

  private obtenerListaEstados() {
    this.controlService.obtenerEstados().subscribe(response => {
      this.estadoModel = response.data;
    })
  }

  cambiarEstado(valor: Event, row: any) {
    this.estadoSeleccionado = valor;
    this.idSeleccionado = row.idControl;
    console.log(" ID SELECC " +this.idSeleccionado );
    console.log(" ESTADO SELECC " +this.estadoSeleccionado );
  }

  changeValue(e: any) {
    console.log(" INPUT  " +e.value);
    this.comentIngresado = e.value;
  }

  guardar(){
    if(this.comentIngresado == "" &&  this.idSeleccionado ==""){
      alert("No se han modificado campos");
    }else{
      console.log(" ENTRA ELSE  " +this.comentIngresado + " "+this.idSeleccionado);
    }
    
  }
}
```

y asi como esta lo hace,  es correcto o la mejor forma de hacer la validacion de campos en el metodo **guardar**?, lo que no se, es como obtener el id de la fila donde quiero modificar el campo **COMENTARIO**, porque cuando se selecciona otro estatus de la lista , si obtengo el id , pero cuando solo se modifica el campo COMENTARIO , no y necesito sacarlo para hacer el update por id, cómo lo puedo sacar?

Comment: Si agregas un solo botón para guardar toda la tabla en lugar de por filas lo que vas a hacer es enviar toda la tabla cada vez que edites lo mínimo. Lo mejor sería agregar botones para editar / eliminar cada fila.